# Trying to make split in C++, get error: "cli::array<System::String> ^,1> has no member split"

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

I'm using Visual Studio, C++ project and windows form. When I'm trying make split a String. Code below:

```
String^ originalString = textBox1->Text;//original text string
cli::array<String^>^ sentence= originalString->Split('.');//text is being split into sentences    
cli::array<String^>^ words= sentence->Split(' ');// text is being split into words, also I get ERROR HERE
for (int i = 0; i < words->Length; ++i)
{
    datagridview1->Rows[i]->Cells[2]->Value = i;
}
```

Error message: "`cli::array<System::String> ^,1>` has no member split"

Comment: As the error says: The array class doesn't have a function called `Split`.

Comment: There is no C++ here, just C++/CLI.

Answer (score 2):

```
cli::array<String^>^ words= sentence->Split(' ');
```

`sentence` is an array of `String^`, so you can't apply `Split` to it. You need to iterate over each element of the array (i.e., each sentence), and apply `Split` to it to get the words:

```
for each(auto sent in sentence)
    cli::array<String^>^ words = sent->Split(' ');
```

Comment: The syntax is `for each(auto sent in sentence)`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, thanks, I'm not too familiar with cli :S

Comment: No problem :) IIRC this syntax existed in C++/CLI before the `for(auto x : y)` one of C++11.